# When did it become OK to use UTF-8?

Tags: html, http, text, encoding

When did people start using UTF-8 in files encoding and HTTP Content-Type headers? Since all web servers, OSes, text editors and browsers support it today, when did it become "compatible" between these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this picture might be useful:

[image]

**Edit:** I found a [later version](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/unicode-nearing-50-of-web.html):

[image]

Comment: Awesome. So the answer is “2008”.

Comment: 2008 is when it became "mainstream". Everybody cool's using UTF-32 now :)

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 has always been [backwards compatible with ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

So basically, it's been OK to use UTF-8 since it's been OK to use ASCII (which is quite a long time).

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Even though it's compatible with ASCII, if the browser didn't know about it, it could easily have thrown a wobbly.

Comment: Not quite. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding and there were quite a few systems that (ab)used the 8th bit for their own purpose which broke UTF-8. For a while there was even "UTF-7" which was invented to work around this problem, but thankfuly the world adopted UTF-8 so UTF-7 is now mostly resting in piece.

Comment: @Jon Good point. Feel free to give a more thorough answer (or edit mine) if you fancy it :)